# How to solve multivariate inequalities with python and sympy?

Tags: python, sympy, inequalities

I'm quite new using python and Sympy... And got a problem to solve multivariate inequalities using sympy.

Let's say I have a lot of functions in a file which look like this :

```
    cst**(sqrt(x)/2)/cst
    exp(sqrt(cst*x**(1/4)))
    log(log(sqrt(cst + exp(x))))
    (y**(1/4) + y)**cst
    sqrt(y/log(x))/cst
    sqrt(cst**log(cst) + x)
    (y**2)**(x/4)
    sqrt(y*sqrt(cst**y))
    log(sqrt(2)*sqrt(cst)*x)
```

I need to derivate them, set the value of the constant and check if, for each functions f,

```
    df/dx > 0
    df/dy < 0
```

With x in [0, +oo) and y in [0, 1].

To derivate i use :

```
    dx = diff(f, x)
    dy = diff(f, y)
```

Then when i try :

```
    cst = 2 #(for example) 
    solve(dx > 0)
```

I got this error :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/solvers/solvers.py", line 634, in solve
symbols=symbols)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/solvers/inequalities.py", line 374, in reduce_inequalities
    raise NotImplementedError("only univariate inequalities are supported")
    NotImplementedError: only univariate inequalities are supported
```

But if i try that :

```
    x=Symbol('x', real=True, postive=True, nonzero=True)
    y=Symbol('y', real=True, postive=True, nonzero=True)
    solve(x**2+y > 0)
```

I got :

```
    True
```

Which is good and workable answer.
Is there anyway to solve multivariate inequalities and always get an workable answer?

For example I would like to get : 
        solve(x**2-y>0)
        Or(x>-sqrt(y), x>sqrt(y))

Comment: Welcome! Do not forget that the etiquette here is to explain what you have tried and why it did not work when asking a questions.

Comment: Aïe, i'll not forget next time! I did try the same code as you... And get the same answer : "NotImplementedError".

Answer (score 9):

When trying to solve this with SymPy you get a pretty clear error message: `NotImplementedError: only univariate inequalities are supported`. Be aware that this means that the SymPy team will be very happy if you contribute an algorithm that solves this problem.

Now that it is clear that `sympy.solve` is not powerful enough you can try another approach. Recently (in 0.7.2) an implicit plotting routine was added to sympy that can plot where an expression evaluates to `True`. Regretfully it is only a numeric solution, not a symbolic one that you can get from `solve` but it might be enough:

[image]

From the image you can see that there is only a single line where the expression changes sign, so solving for `expr==0` might give you what you want. And this is indeed the case:

[image]

Comment: Thand for answering, but it'll not be good for what I need.

I have to generate all possible functions f(x,y), for example with 10 characters, and then evaluate all derivatives to check if :

    df/dx > 0 and 
    df/dy < 0.                                               
There are to much possibilities to be able to check everything by myself...

Got any idea about that?

Comment: I really do not understand how what you ask in the comment is in any way related to what you have asked in the question above? Feel free to ask a new question, or if you insist to modify the original one so it clear what you want. Upvote if you find an answer useful.

Comment: Excellent and thorough answer.  The explanation helped with my game theory core allocation calculation.

Answer (score 4):

There is a multivariate inequality solver in `mystic`, which is built on top of `sympy`.  It uses optimization and the (mathematical) mapping of sets to provide this feature.  It's not perfect, but works for many cases.

```
>>> equations = '''
... 2*A + 3*B >= C
... A*B > D
... C < 4*A    
... D == 0
... '''
>>> 
>>> import mystic.symbolic as ms
>>> var = list('ABCD')
>>> eqns = ms.simplify(equations, variables=var)
>>> print eqns
D == 0
B > 0
A > C/4
A >= -3*B/2 + C/2
A > D/B
>>> 
>>> # generate a constraints function, which maps one space to another
>>> constrain = ms.generate_constraint(ms.generate_solvers(eqns, var))
>>> solution = constrain([1,2,3,4])
>>> print solution
[1, 2, 3, 0] 
>>> # here's the solution...
>>> dict(zip(var,solution))
{'A': 1, 'C': 3, 'B': 2, 'D': 0}
>>>
>>> A=1; C=3; B=2; D=0
>>> 2*A + 3*B >= C
True
>>> A*B > D
True
>>> C < 4*A
True
>>> D == 0
True
>>>
```

Let's do it again, with the suggested test:

```
>>> equations = """x**2 - y >= 0
... x + y = 0
... """
>>> eqns = ms.simplify(equations, variables=var)
>>> constrain = ms.generate_constraint(ms.generate_solvers(eqns, var))
>>> solution = constrain([1,3])
>>> solution
[-3, 3]
>>> dict(zip(var, solution))
{'y': 3, 'x': -3}
>>> y=3; x=-3
>>> x**2 - y >= 0
True
>>> x+y == 0
True
>>>
```

`mystic` uses a combination of `sympy` and numerical optimization to simplify inequalities; and when presented with an initial guess solution, can (most of the time, but not always) generate a valid solution to the equations.  `mystic` won't actually **solve** the inequalities per se, but it will (usually) generate a valid solution to the inequalities.