# Solving a non-linear system on Python

Tags: python, optimization, linear-algebra, nonlinear-optimization

I usually rely on Wolfram Mathematica for this kind of thing, but I've been delving into Python recently and the results are so much better. Basically, I'm looking for numerical solutions for systems like the following.

system:
[image: system]

Well, I know that there are solutions, because Wolfram Mathematica found a single one (0.0858875,0.0116077,-0.156661,1.15917). What I tried to do in Python is this brute force code.

```
import numpy as np

START = -3
END = 3
STEP = 0.1

for r0 in np.arange(START, END, STEP):
    for r1 in np.arange(START, END, STEP):
        for r2 in np.arange(START, END, STEP):
            for r3 in np.arange(START, END, STEP):
                eq0 = r0*r2+r1*r3
                eq1 = r0*r1+r1*r2+r2*r3+r0*r3
                eq2 = r0**2+r1**2+r2**2+r3**2-4*(r0+r1+r2+r3)**2

                if (eq0 == 0 and eq1 < 0 and eq2 < 0): 
                    print(r0, r1, r2, r3)
```

**Edit:** I'm okay with things like -0.00001< eq0 < 0.00001 instead of eq1 == 0

Well, although it didn't find solutions in this case, the brute force method went well for other systems I'm dealing with, particularly when there are fewer equations and variables. Starting with four variables, it becomes really difficult.

I'm sorry if I'm asking too much. I'm completely new to Python, so I also don't know if this is actually trivial. Maybe **fsolve** would be useful? I'm not sure if it works with inequalities. Also, even when the systems I encounter have only equalities, they always have more variables than equations, like this one:
system2:
[image: system2].

Hence 'fsolve' is not appropriate, right?

Comment: Never compare float for equality it is source of problem. Use a epsilon ball instead as you suggested.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32871083/3067485

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as your system contains inequalities, you need to formulate it as an optimization problem and solve it with [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html). Otherwise, you can use [`scipy.optimize.root`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html) or `scipy.optimize.fsolve` to solve an equation system. Note that the former is also exactly what is done behind the scenes in `root` and `fsolve`, i.e. both solve a least-squares optimization problem.

In general, the problem

```
g_1(x) = 0, ..., g_m(x) = 0
h_1(x) < 0, ..., h_p(x) < 0
```

can be formulated as

```
min g_1(x)**2 + ... + g_m(x)**2

s.t. -1.0*(h_1(x) + eps) >= 0
                  .
                  .
     -1.0*(h_p(x) + eps) >= 0
```

where `eps` is a tolerance to model the strict inequality.

Hence, you can solve your first problem as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def obj(r):
    return (r[0]*r[2]+r[1]*r[3])**2

eps = 1.0e-6

constrs = [
    {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda r: -1.0*(r[0]*r[1] + r[1]*r[2] + r[2]*r[3] + r[0]*r[3] + eps)},
    {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda r: -1.0*(np.sum(r**2) - 4*(np.sum(r))**2 + eps)}
]

# res.x contains the solution
res = minimize(obj, x0=np.ones(4), constraints=constrs)
```

Your second problem can be solved similarly. Here, you only need to remove the constraints. Alternatively, you can use [`root`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html) where it's worth mentioning that it solves `F(x) = 0` for a function `F: R^N -> R^N`, i.e. a function of `N` variables that returns an `N` dimensional vector. In case your function has fewer equations than variables, you can simply fill up the vector with zeros:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import root

def F(r):
    vals = np.zeros(r.size)
    vals[0] = np.dot(r[:5], r[1:]) + r[0]*r[5]
    vals[1] = r[0]*r[3] + r[1]*r[4] + r[2]*r[5]
    vals[2] = np.sum(r**2) - 3*np.sum(r)**2
    return vals

# res.x contains your solution
res = root(F, x0=np.ones(6))
```

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you so much. I've been exploring 'scipy.optimize' and I just have a couple questions. If the system only contains inequalities, then I just define `def obj(r): return 0`, correct? It seems to work fine. Second thing is: sometimes I add more constraints and the code gives me results that are not actually solutions, i.e., the contraints are not respected. This means that I need to change the initial guess x0, correct? Also seems to work. Thank you again. I learned a lot through your code.

Comment: @WilliamLima You're welcome. And the answer is 'yes' to both of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but you can simplify this a lot using `product`

```
from itertools import product
import numpy as np


START = -3
END = 3
STEP = 0.1

for r0, r1, r2, r3 in product(np.arange(START, END, STEP), repeat=4):
    print(r0, r1, r2, r3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if your problem is a root finding problem or a minimization with constraints problem, but take a look at scipy.optimize and scipy.linprog, maybe one of those methods can be bent to your application.